# The preparation of ethene from ethanol

Tags: reaction-mechanism, thermodynamics, analytical-chemistry, electrostatic-energy

Draw an energy profile diagram for the dehydration of ethanol to produce ethene, labeling your reactants, products as well as intermediates.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## Define energy levels

reactants_energy = 0
transition_state_energy = 100  # Example value
intermediate_energy = 50  # Example value
products_energy = 20  # Example value

## Define labels

labels = ['Reactants', 'Transition State', 'Intermediate', 'Products']

## Define energies list

energies = [reactants_energy, transition_state_energy, intermediate_energy, products_energy]

## Create energy profile diagram

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.plot(labels, energies, marker='o')
plt.xlabel('Reaction Progress')
plt.ylabel('Energy (kJ/mol)')
plt.title('Energy Profile Diagram for Dehydration of Ethanol to Ethene')
plt.grid(True)
plt.ylim(0, max(energies) + 20)  # Adjust ylim for better visualization
plt.annotate('Activation Energy', xy=(1, transition_state_energy), xytext=(1.2, transition_state_energy + 10),
arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', arrowstyle='->'))
for i in range(len(labels)):
plt.text(labels[i], energies[i] + 5, f'{energies[i]} kJ/mol', ha='center', va='bottom')
plt.show()